# A cota do firebase é por conta ou pro projeto?

Tags: firebase

Galera, estou com uma dúvida quanto a cota do firebase, nesse link há as informações de cotas do firebase https://firebase.google.com/pricing/?hl=pt-br. Porém a página não informa se a cota é por conta ou por projeto. Gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar.
Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achei uma resposta em um outro canal de discussão.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609983/does-the-firebase-spark-free-plan-work-on-a-per-project-basis

Atualmente sei que cada serviço tem suas próprias características de exceção, porém no pacote Free todos os projetos dependem da mesma exceção. No pacote Flame e Blaze as exceções são por projeto e não por cota.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.